# Pipe demon output to a function

Tags: bash, shell-script, mqtt

I'm receiving a MQTT message with mosquitto_sub and I want to redirect the output (two strings) to a function.

CLIENT:

```
mosquitto_pub -d -t hello/world/ -m "Alessio,base64"
```

On the server I have a bash program

SERVER: (it works)

```
function pipeTee(){
        tee -a mqtt_broker.log
}
mosquitto_sub -t +/# | pipeTee
```

but if I try t pipe to another function too, the program doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
function testPipe(){
        echo "va"
}

function pipeTee(){
        tee -a mqtt_broker.log
}
mosquitto_sub -t +/# | pipeTee | testPipe
```

mosquitto_pub from client:

```
mosquitto_pub -d -t hello/world -m "Aless,base64"
Client mosqpub/1841-raspberryp sending CONNECT
Client mosqpub/1841-raspberryp received CONNACK
Client mosqpub/1841-raspberryp sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m1, 'hello/world', ... (12 bytes))
Client mosqpub/1841-raspberryp sending DISCONNECT
```

Server when not working:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./mqtt_broker.sh 
va
^C
```

and the file log is empty

Comment: Does `mosquitto_sub` exit back to the shell after running? What is the output of that command?

Comment: yes, but the problem is in in the shell script. It0s normal for mosquitto_pub to exit after the command

Comment: your `testPipe` function exits after its echo. This means any writes from the tee will receive a signal SIGPIPE broken pipe, and so tee will die. You would need, eg, to add a `cat` to the end of your function.

Comment: where? I didn't understand, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following shell script:

```
function thetee {
    tee data.out
}

function thepipe {
    echo "Hello!"
}

while true; do
    echo "Hi there!"
done | thetee | thepipe

echo "Done."
```

The `while`-loop here is a generator of unlimited lines with the text "Hi there!".

Running it:

```
$ sh script.sh
Hello!
Done.
```

Then look at the number of lines in `data.out`:

```
$ wc -l data.out
     274 data.out
```

Again:

```
$ sh script.sh
Hello!
Done.

$ wc -l data.out
     236 data.out
```

**Issues:**

1. The infinite loop isn't infinite.
2. The number of lines of output differs between runs.

**Reasons:**

1. The `thepipe` function in my example simply echoes a string, then exits, causing the pipe to fail.  No further input can be processed by the last stage of the pipeline and the loop exits.
2. The number of lines actually written to `data.out` depends on how quickly the shell is able to start up the pipeline and how quickly the `thepipe` function can do its thing and exit.

In your case, this happens so quickly that no input from the data generator (`mosquitto_sub`) is able to arrive to the `tee` function.

**Solution:**

Make `thepipe` function actually *consume its input*:

```
function thepipe {
    echo "Hello!"
    cat
}
```

This will make the code in my example output a single "Hello!" followed by infinite "Hi there!" (which are also saved into `data.out`). The `echo` at the end will never be executed.

**Therefore:**

Change the definition of you `testPipe` function in a similar manner. For example:

```
function testPipe(){
        echo "va"
        cat
}
```

This will have the effect of consuming the input, and sending it on to the next stage of the pipeline, or, if it's at the end of a pipeline, to wherever standard output is redirected after it (with a line containing the string `va` at the start of the stream).